# How to make a parallel join on two tables and order result by creation date?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I'm new at using PL/SQL language and i'm facing this problem :
Assuming that I have Table A , B and C as :
 A  1 --- *  B
 A  1 --- *  C

I'm using the following script :

```
Select B.b, C.c
From A,B,C
WHERE A.id = B.a_id
OR A.id = C.a_id 
ORDER BY B.creation_Date,C.creation_Date ;
```

What I get is :

|  b            |  c            |

---

```
val_b_1      |  val_c_1
val_b_1      |  val_c_2   
val_b_1      |  val_c_3
val_b_11     |  val_c_11
val_b_12     |  val_c_11
```

what I want to get is :

|  b            |  c            |

---

```
val_b_1      | 
             |  val_c_1
             |  val_c_2   
             |  val_c_3
val_b_11     | 
             |  val_c_11
val_b_12     |
```

Ordered By creation date of both C & B.
How can I do that?

Comment: Please be more clear about your environment. PL/SQL is an Oracle proprietary language for programming. Your question seems to be dealing with plain SQL. If you really are in MySQL, please remove the "oracle" and 'plsql" tags.

Comment: Hi,I'm using PL/SQL

Comment: But there is no PL/SQL in your question. (And why is it tagged `mysql`? It can't be both.)

Comment: Post your sample data in each table as well/

Answer (score 1):

I think it should look like this:

```
Select B.b, C.c
From A
LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON B.a_id = A.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN C ON C.a_id = A.id
ORDER BY B.creation_Date,C.creation_Date ;
```

Comment: Hi @CptMisery I tried this but still not getting what I want

Comment: How about this? `Select B.b, C.c
From A,B,C
WHERE (A.id = B.a_id AND C.a_id IS NULL)
OR (A.id = C.a_id AND B.a_id IS NULL)
ORDER BY B.creation_Date,C.creation_Date ;`